# Laravel showing wrong locale

Tags: php, laravel, config, locale

For some reason when I do `dump(app()->getLocale());` it is returning `fr` when it should be `en`.

In my `config/app.php` I have the following:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
'locale' => 'en',
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

I have cleared my cache numerous times with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`, I have restarted my server but `app()->getLocale()` always returns `fr`.

Anyone know why this is?

I am using Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.

Comment: You may have `setLocale()` at some point. Have you tried finding one?

Comment: Not from my own code. Only in the test classes in the core Symfony modules that come as part of Laravel.